# ¿Como enviar parámetros por petición GET desde un iframe que contiene una ruta de Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

¿Como enviar parámetros por petición GET desde un iframe que contiene una ruta de Angular?
Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente frame:

```
    <frame src="http://localhost:8080/front-web/novedades"/>
```

y quiero enviar parametros por GET, seria algo asi:

```
    <frame src="http://localhost:8080/front-web/novedades?usuario=juan&apellido=ruiz"/>
```

¿Se podría así? 
¿Ademas como capturo los parámetros en angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de hacer lo que queria:

Para hacer la petición desde el frame a una ruta de Angular **NO** la hago asi:

```
        <frame src="http://localhost:8080/front-web/novedades?usuario=juan&apellido=ruiz"/>
```

La manera correcta es:

```
        <frame src="http://localhost:8080/front-web/novedades/juan/ruiz"/>
```

Ademas, en el archivo de rutas de Angular (en mi caso router.js) se debe modificar para poder capturar los parámetros de la siguiente manera:

```
.when('/novedades/:param1/:param2', {
        templateUrl: 'miurlnovedades.html',
        controller: 'micontroladornovedades'
```

Lo importante es la parte donde recibe los parametros:

```
    .when('/novedades/:param1/:param2', {
```

En mi controlador debo inyectar $routeParams:

```
    angular.module("app").controller('micontroladornovedades', function($scope, $routeParams...
```

y en cualquier parte del controlador ya obtengo los parámetros capturados en el archivo de rutas de la siguiente manera:

```
    var usuario = $routeParams.param1;
    var apellido = $routeParams.param2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Las dos respuesta que te dieron son validas debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

1. Que enrutador estas usando ui-router ó ngRoute
2. Verifica en el state o router como tienes definidos por parametros (puedes ser por (?  y &) ó por /)

Comment: Es ngRoute y esta definido por parámetros con /

Comment: tu error es que tienes <frame> cambialo a iframe, ademas en tu state debe de tener que recibes un parametro y en el controller no se te olvide el stateParams

Answer (score 0):

Los frames se montan durante la carga de la página así que si quieres cambiar el contenido del frame tendrías que cambiarlo después de la carga cambiando la propiedad `src` del mismo, por ejemplo, así: `document.getElementById('content2').src = "http://localhost:8080/front-web/novedades?usuario=juan&apellido=ruiz"`.

Prueba eso a ver si te sirve.

Comment: Creo que no es lo que quiero.
De todos modos gracias por responder Fernando Forcén.
Acabo de solucionarlo, abajo pongo la solución.

Comment: Lo importante es que lo hayas solucionado ;)